WebRTC Remote Stream not displaying
I checked the events ontrack and I see I have the correct media object of the remote, however, it's not displaying anything else, my local stream is fine btw.
function GroupCall() {

const socket = useSocket();
const { user } = userStateContext();
let { room } = useParams();
const peer_ref = useRef(null);
const localStream = useRef();
const remoteStream = useRef();
room = room.replace( 'ROOM:', '' );

const [ isMounted, setMount ] = useState(false);

const create_offer = () => {
    return new Promise(( resolve, reject) => {
        peer_ref.current.createOffer().then( offer => {
            return peer_ref.current.setLocalDescription( offer );
        }).then( () => {
            resolve( peer_ref.current.localDescription );
        }).catch( error => {
            console.error( 'Error local creating offer: ', error );
            reject( error );
        });
    })
};

const create_answer = ( data ) => {
    return new Promise(( resolve, reject) => {
        peer_ref.current.setRemoteDescription( data.remote_description ).then(() => {
            return peer_ref.current.createAnswer();
        }).then( ( answer ) => {
            return peer_ref.current.setLocalDescription( answer );
        }).then( () => {
            resolve( peer_ref.current.localDescription );
        }).catch( ( error ) => {
            console.error( 'Error answering the offer description: ', error );
            reject( error );
        });
    });
}

const establish_remote_description = (data) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        peer_ref.current.setRemoteDescription( data.remote_description ).then(() => {
            resolve( true );
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error( 'Error answered offer description: ', error );
            reject( error );
        });
    });
}

const get_user_media = async () => {
    try {
        return await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error accessing media devices:', error);
    }
}

useEffect(() => {

    if ( !isMounted && socket ) {

        get_user_media().then( (stream) => {

            peer_ref.current = new RTCPeerConnection();

            peer_ref.current.ontrack = (event) => {
                if (event.streams && event.streams.length > 0) {
                    console.log( event );
                    const remoteVideo = remoteStream.current;
                    remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
                    remoteVideo.onloadedmetadata = () => {
                        remoteVideo.play().catch((error) => {
                            console.error('Failed to start video playback:', error);
                        });
                    };
                }
            };

            // peer_ref.current.onicecandidate = (event) => {
            //     if ( event.candidate ) {
            //         console.log( event.candidate );
            //     } else {
            //         console.log( "ICE gathering complete" );
            //     }
            // };

            if ( stream ) {

                localStream.current.srcObject = stream;
                localStream.current.play();

                stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
                    peer_ref.current.addTrack( track, stream );
                });

                create_offer().then(( local_description ) =>  {
                    socket.emit( 'register_user', user.id );
                    socket.emit( 'register_user_room_call', {
                        'user_id': user.id,
                        'room': room,
                        'local_description': local_description
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        socket.on( 'received_request_call_answer', ( data ) => {
            if ( data.from !== user.id ) {
                create_answer( data ).then(( local_description ) => {
                    console.log( 'offer: ', data );
                    socket.emit( 'send_answered_call', {
                        'from': user.id,
                        'to_user_id': data.from,
                        'local_description': local_description
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        socket.on( 'received_answered_call', ( data ) => {
            if ( data.from !== user.id ) {
                establish_remote_description( data ).then( () => {
                    console.log( 'accept: ', data );
                });
            }
        });

        setMount( true );

        return () => {
            socket.off( 'request_call_answer', create_answer );
            socket.off( 'received_answered_call', establish_remote_description );
        };
    }
}, [isMounted, room, socket, user.id]);

return (
    <div className="relative flex flex-col h-screen">
        <div className="flex flex-row justify-between p-4 px-7">
            <div className="flex flex-row gap-3">
                <img
                    src={user.profile_picture ?? profilePic}
                    className="w-[40px] h-[40px] md:w-[50px] md:h-[50px] rounded-full object-cover border-gray-300 border-2 p-[.030rem]"
                    alt="Cover"
                />
                <div className="flex flex-col gap-1 pt-0">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-row gap-3">
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faEllipsis}
                    className="font-extrabold p-1 rounded h-[1.5rem] w-[1.5rem] custom-hover"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <video ref={remoteStream} autoPlay playsInline className='w-full border max-h[300px]'/>
        <div className="w-full flex flex-row justify-center items-center gap-3 p-10">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faDisplay} className="custom-hover h-[1.5rem] w-[1.5rem] p-2 rounded-xl"
                             title="Share your screen"/>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faVideo} className="custom-hover h-[1.5rem] w-[1.5rem] p-2 rounded-xl"
                             title="Turn off video"/>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMicrophone}
                             className="custom-hover h-[1.5rem] w-[1.5rem] p-2 rounded-xl"
                             title="Mute microphone"/>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRightFromBracket}
                             className="custom-hover h-[1.5rem] w-[1.5rem] p-2 rounded-xl bg-red-800"
                             title="End call"/>
        </div>
        <Card
            className="fixed right-[3rem] top-[4rem] h-[25%] w-[25%] rounded-xl bg-gray-800 overflow-hidden">
            <video ref={localStream} autoPlay playsInline className='w-full h-full'/>
        </Card>
    </div>
);

and here is the ontrack event logs:
isTrusted: true,
bubbles: false,
cancelBubble: false,
cancelable: false,
composed: false,
currentTarget: RTCPeerConnection,
defaultPrevented: false,
eventPhase: 0,
receiver: RTCRtpReceiver,
returnValue: true,
srcElement: RTCPeerConnection,
target: RTCPeerConnection,
timeStamp: 6902.4000000059605,
track: MediaStreamTrack,
transceiver: RTCRtpTransceiver,
type: "track",
streams: [MediaStream]

User1:
currentLocalDescription: RTCSessionDescription {type: 'answer', sdp: 'v=0\r\no=- 8453598831410487915 3 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns…0K98Y

currentRemoteDescription: RTCSessionDescription {type: 'offer', sdp: 'v=0\r\no=- 4335048930304532641 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns…d246f

User2:
currentLocalDescription: RTCSessionDescription {type: 'offer', sdp: 'v=0\r\no=- 4335048930304532641 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns…d246fbe

currentRemoteDescription: RTCSessionDescription {type: 'answer', sdp: 'v=0\r\no=- 8453598831410487915 3 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns…0K98

No errors were displayed, I also tried to print the event.streams[0] and it shows the following media object below as expected:
{
active: true
id: "unique ID here..."
onactive: null
onaddtrack: null
oninactive: null
onremovetrack: null
}

maybe because I haven't setup the icecandidate? such as the 'addIceCandidate'...

ICE candidates contain the remote IP address to connect to. Without that you will not get very far...
